# Let X and Y are independent random variables, why does the variance of XY end up being 0 in my formulation?

Tags: probability, statistics

Note that $E[\cdot]$ denotes an expectation value, $V[\cdot]$ means a variance and, $\mu, \upsilon$ are expectation values of independent random variables X, Y respectively.

In my formulation, the variance of XY is equal to

$V[XY]= E[(XY-E[XY])^2]$..(i)

since  $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]=\mu \upsilon$,

(i)=$E[(XY-\mu \upsilon)^2]=E[(XY)^2-2\mu \upsilon XY+(\mu \upsilon)^2]$
=$E[(XY)^2]-2\mu \upsilon E[XY]+(\mu \upsilon)^2$...(ii)

Now the sum (ii) is equal to zero due to $E[(XY)^2]=\mu^2 \upsilon^2$

I know this is wrong cuz a variance = $0$ means the random variable perfectly matches its expectation value, which would not happen in the real world. Where is the incorrect formulation?

Comment: If $\mu,\upsilon$ are the expectations of $X,Y$ then $E[(XY)^2]=\mu^2 \upsilon^2$ looks wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your last line is wrong. Due to independence,
$$\mathbb{E}[(XY)^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2Y^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=(\text{Var}(X) + \mu^2)(\text{Var}(Y) + \nu^2)$$
So, you get
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(XY) &= \text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y) + \mu^2\text{Var}(Y) + \nu^2\text{Var}(X) + \mu^2\nu^2 - \mu^2\nu^2 \\
&= \text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y) + \mu^2\text{Var}(Y) + \nu^2\text{Var}(X)
\end{align*}
which is the correct formula.

Comment: Boys and girls! The last equals sign in the  first line is true only when $\mu,\upsilon$ are zero.

Comment: @KurtG. Indeed.  $\mathsf E(X^2)=\mathsf{Var}(X)+\mu^2$ and $\mathsf E(Y^2)=\mathsf{Var}(Y)+\nu^2$, so...

Comment: Oh of course, careless of me. Edited to fix.

Comment: Now the first line looks correct. The second line?
$$
{\rm Var}(XY)=\mathbb E[(XY)^2]\color{red}{-\mu^2\nu^2}\,.
$$

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, I had it right on paper and then wrote down the wrong thing...

Comment: Can happen. Some obvious sanity checks are: what must ${\rm Var}(XY)$ be when ${\rm Var}(X)=0$ or ${\rm Var}(Y)=0\,.$ As far as I see that formula passes now.

Comment: Thank you guys!! It totally makes sense!